# How can create email id using shell_exec or exec in php?

Tags: php, linux

How can create email id using `shell_exec` or `exec` commands in PHP.

That is: I want to create an email id in my web application.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you've got a few choices, but most aren't practical from a web script point of view, as they require root permissions and/or substantial modifications to the server for initial setup.

1. add an entry to /etc/aliases to forward your new virtual mailbox to an existing account (on the same system or elsewhere) (requires root permissions)
2. create a physical system account (requires root permissions)
3. Set up a virtual mail server using a standard SMTP server, mysql, and dovecot (I've used postfix for this successfully). Much harder, but makes adding accounts a snap as it's simply a new database record.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an php email library like swiftmailer: http://swiftmailer.org/

It would be possible to compose an email by "exec" and another tool, but there are too many risks/problems with that approach.

Comment: Probably you are talking something different from what is being asked. The ask is to "create email id using shell_exec or exec commands in php", while you are talking about "composing email".

Answer (score 0):

In other words @Tobias, shahul it trying to create an e-mail account from command line.

@shahul, what kind of e-mail account are you trying to create? Is it a GMail/Yahoo!, etc free e-mail account or are you talking from an MTA level, and if an MTA, what operating system and MTA are you talking about?

Comment: iam trying to create email account in MTA level and i am using linux operating system

Comment: Then your code will depend on the specific MTA that you are using. Which one are you using? QMail, Postfix, Exim, sendmail, other?